# How to wrap plain function into a constructor?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a wrapper function `MyFunction`, which when called with `new` as in

```
instance = new MyFunction();
```

really returns the same object as if the callsite called `SomeOtherFunction` without `new`?

```
instance = SomeOtherFunction();
```

*(I've looked at [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) but doesn't look like they're supported in Chrome yet.)*

#### Edit:

It turns out the callsite calls `MyFunction` like this:

```
var instance = Object.create(MyFunction.prototype);
MyFunction.apply(instance, [/* arguments */]);
// `instance` is supposed to be initialized here
```

Comment: Sure: `function MyFunction() { return SomeOtherFunction(); }`

Comment: @FelixKling I already tried that—`new MyFunction()` returns a blank object with none of the same properties as `SomeOtherFunction()`.

Comment: But why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mksios unlikely. Is the return value of `SomeOtherFunction` an object? Constructors can only return objects.

Comment: @ArnarYngvason the callsite, which I can't modify, expects a constructor. `SomeOtherFunction`, which I also can't modify, is a plain function which returns a new object. I want to link the two.

Comment: You need to provide more information, because what is said works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a568cpLg/.

Comment: Can you include some more example code in the question?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes `SomeOtherFunction` basically does `return new SomeOtherObject(...)`

Comment: If `SomeOtherFunction` really does that, then there is no need to wrap it. Calling it with or without `new` won't make a difference.

Comment: I'd like to know what `SomeOtherFunction` looks like.

Comment: @ArnarYngvason after some more digging, I see that `SomeOtherFunction` is a wrapper which does `return ReactDOM.render(...)` which returns a React component object (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html)

Comment: So was is a React question all along... I think your question needs more context.

Comment: In your edit, is `instance` supposed to be `expr`?

Comment: @torazaburo, yes, fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for? Note as Jan Dvorak mentioned, you can only return objects.

```
function SomeObject() {
    return Construct();
}

function Construct() {
    return { 'name' : 'yessirrreee' };
}

console.log(new SomeObject())
```

Comment: Yeah I can confirm the object is being passed through in this example, but after digging a bit on my side I found the callsite is calling the constructor a bit differently (see edits)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function MyClass() {
}

var ob = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit after comments

I think this questions needs more context.
I suggest you read about [higher order components](http://jamesknelson.com/structuring-react-applications-higher-order-components/), but until you've better clarified what exactly you're trying to accomplish, I cannot help you.

---

I really don't know what your code looks like, but here are some suggestions
either way. My guess nr2 is what you're looking for:

```
// 1
function MyFunction() {
  this.__proto__ = SomeOtherFunction()
}

function SomeOtherFunction() {
  return {
    foo: function() {
      return 'bar'
    }
  }
}

var fn = new MyFunction()
fn.foo()

// 2
function MyFunction() {}
MyFunction.prototype = SomeOtherFunction()

function SomeOtherFunction() {
  return {
    foo: function() {
      return 'bar'
    }
  }
}

var fn = new MyFunction()
fn.foo()

// 3
function MyFunction() {}
MyFunction.prototype = SomeOtherFunction.prototype

function SomeOtherFunction() {
  function Foo() {}
  Foo.prototype.foo = function() {
    return 'bar'
  }
}

var fn = new MyFunction()
fn.foo()
```